# Webhooks per entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-webhooks

I'm using the [ASP.NET Webhooks](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks) packages to allow users to receive callbacks when certain events occur in my application.
e.g. entityUpdated, entityCreated, entityDeleted

I would like to expose the possibility to users of registering Webhooks only for updates on specific entities in case they are only interested in receiving callbacks for those specific entities.
e.g. entityUpdated for entity1

The filters seem like a good candidate for implementing this behavior. Users can subscribe to events using filters.
e.g. entity* (to receive all event concerning entities)

So I was thinking of exposing events per entity like: entity_1_Updated.
That would mean the list of exposed event will change during the runtime of the application (as entities get created or deleted).
More concrete, the implementation of IWebHookFilterProvider would perform a database query to fetch the list of entities for wich events can occur.
Like so:

```
class EntityWebHookFilterProvider : IWebHookFilterProvider
{
    public async Task<Collection<WebHookFilter>> GetFiltersAsync()
    {
        List<int> ids = await repository.GetAllUpdatableEntitiesAsync();
        return new Collection<WebHookFilter>(ids.Select(id => new WebHookFilter { Name = string.Format("entity_{0}_Updated", id)}).ToList());
    }
}
```

Would this be a good solution? Or should the list of events/filters be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way may be to use a separate field in the registration to indicate the specific ID the subscriber is interested in using the Properties part of the WebHook registration.

Then when you send a notification on the server side you can use the overload which takes a Func enabling you to filter that WebHooks only are generated when the ID matches that of the WebHook registration, for example:

```
// Create an event with action 'event1' and additional data
await this.NotifyAsync("event1", new { P1 = "p1" }, (w, s) =>
{
    // Check that the property included in the event data matches that 
    // of the WebHook registration.
    return true;
});
```

Hope this helps,

Henrik